# A struct containing entire OpenGL ES 2.0 state

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

Has anyone got a C struct that has members describing the entire OpenGL ES 2.0 state? It would look something like that:

```
struct OpenGLES20State
{
  int activeTexture;
  bool scissorEnabled;
  Rectangle scissorRectangle;
  bool stencilEnabled;
  int stencilFunc;
  int stencilOpFail;
  int stencilOpDFail;
  int stencilOpDPass;
  //
  // and a lot more...
  //
}
```

Comment: This could be very useful for debugging... It would probably be quite a tremendous beast. By the time you put it together, I imagine you've all but re-implemented OpenGL. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can create this structure by carefully working with OpenGL ES 2 specification available from Khronos: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/2_X/

Also, interesting place to look for a similar implementation may be Mesa3D library source code.